# How can I monitor all the outgoing ajax request with selenium-webdriver [IN NODEJS]

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have seen some answers in `JAVA` but I couldn't understand them and Selenium's documentation in `NodeJs` is abysmal.

I am `scraping` a webpage which has just few lines (15-20) of source code and everything else is run by JS. The `webpage` makes certain request with specific queries (which changes from time to time). I want to monitor all the outgoing `ajax` request on this page.

If there are better alternatives than `Selenium` please help me.

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

let driver = new Builder()
.forBrowser('chrome')
.build();

driver.get('https://example.com')
// driver monitor all outgoing ajax request of example.com
```

Comment: Can you share your code trials please?

Comment: I have only initiated the driver but cannot move forward without knowing the selenium commands